# "No such file or directory" when trying tto run script in background from another script

Tags: bash, shell-script

My run.sh script errors out when I try to run another script in the background..

**Console Error String**

```
./run.sh 30: nohup bash /export/home/myself/bin/mytestprogram &>/dev/null & : No such file or directory
```

- can't publish the script because its host machine isn't on the internet.

---

**here is what works**

it builds an absolute path to the target program..

such as:
**Absolute Path to target script**

```
/export/home/myself/bin/mytestprogram
```

which runs fine manually or through the script...  It builds this command line with script variables like so

**Bash Script how I build the command string**

```
cmd="${exedir}/${exe}"
```

and I run this from my script by saying

**Bash Script line which Calls the Target command string**

```
"${cmd}"
```

**all that works..**  So running the script in the foreground works.

---

Now what doesn't work, when I try to run the exact same path and command in the background.

I am trying to run:

**Run in Background Command String**

```
nohup bash /export/home/myself/bin/mytestprogram &>/dev/null &
```

which works when I manually past it from the output of my script to the command line.  When I manually call this on the command line, it works.  My script actually echo's the command to the console and I cut and past it and it works.  But when the run.sh script calls same command, it doesn't work?

I build this with the same variables as the above foreground call like so..

**How the Background Command String is built**

```
cmd="nohup bash ${exedir}/${exe} &>/dev/null &"
```

I echo this command to the console like so:

**How Background Command String is sent to Console**

```
echo -e "$cmd"
```

and call it like so..

```
"$cmd"
```

again my error message is:

**Console Error String**

```
./run.sh 30: nohup bash /export/home/myself/bin/mytestprogram &>/dev/null &
:No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 2):

1. The command I think you're looking for is `nohup`. Not `nohub`.
2. You can't do this:

   ```
   cmd="nohub bash ${exedir}/${exe} &>/dev/null &"
   "${cmd}"
   ```

   What that's doing is trying to run a command consisting of the *single word* `nohub bash /export/home/myself/bin/mytestprogram &>/dev/null &` - *including the spaces and punctuation as part of that single word*. The shell will not evaluate the command and split it at spaces.

There are several answers here, for example [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/100397), that explain how you can safely build a command and then execute it. Personally I think you're probably better off just running the command when you want to use it rather than putting it into a variable and trying to execute its value.